# "to be" vs "be"

Tags: grammar, to-infinitive

I heard many times that people say the verb ***to be*** and wonder why they say **the verb** "to be".

It's "to+infinitive" not a verb, but many people say the verb "to be".

Could anyone explain the reason why it is called 'the verb *to be*'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The to-infinitive is a verb. It's also a handy way to refer to that verb as a lexical item. The monosyllable "be" may not make it clear what one means.